# Limit of a function. Integration problem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

I have this problem:

Let $c\in \mathbb{R}$. If $\int_c^\infty f(x)dx$ converges, then $$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$$ exist and is $0$. Moreover, if $f$ is monotonic, $\lim_{x\to \infty} xf(x)$ exist and is equal to $0$.

Although I can't assume that $f$ is continuous, I have tihis question:

If $F$ is a function with continuous first derivative, such that $$\lim_{x\to \infty}F(x)=L,$$ for some $L\in\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} F'(x)=0\;?$$

Comment: @leo: first work out it for the case when $c=0$. It is simpler.

Comment: @Please see problem **1.5.15** in Kaczor's *Problems in Mathematical Analysis*, Vol III, Integration.

Comment: Then is necessary the uniform continuity of $f$. Thanks @Chandru.

Comment: In the course notes, the problem is as I write here.

Comment: @leo: No i just gave you a similar problem.

Comment: I'm confused.  The part that user6312 answered is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35869/what-does-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fx-1-say-about-lim-limits-x-to-in, but it seems there's more to your question than that.  I do not have Kaczor handy, so I do not know what Chandru's comment is supposed to address.  The first statement in your question is incorrect, but I am not sure if you are asking about that.

Comment: @Jonas: yes I'm asking about the whole problem. And I'm asking also about the question that came to me when I tried to solve it. @Chandru: the answer of user of user6312, gives me a counterexample. Consider $f(x)=2\cos (x^2)-\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$. Then $f$ is not uniform continuous in $[\sqrt{\pi},\infty[$ and the $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)$ does not exist. But $\int_{\sqrt{\pi}}^\infty f(x)dx=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

André already gave you a very simple example, where $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty } F(x) = 0$ but $\underset{x \to \infty }{\lim \sup}\; F'(x) = 2$ and $\underset{x \to \infty }{\lim \inf}\;  F'(x) = -2$ (since $F'(x) = 2\cos (x^2 ) - \frac{{\sin (x^2 )}}{{x^2 }}$). Modifying $F$ to $F(x) = \frac{{\sin (x^3 )}}{x}$, we moreover get an example with $\underset{x \to \infty }{\lim \sup}\;  F'(x) = \infty$ and $\underset{x \to \infty }{\lim \inf}\;  F'(x) = -\infty$ (since $F'(x)=3x\cos (x^3 ) - \frac{{\sin (x^3 )}}{{x^2 }}$). Obviously, in both examples, $F$ is not a monotone function.

Let's now give an example of a (continuously differentiable) monotone increasing function $F$ with $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty } F(x) = 1$, for which, nevertheless, $\underset{x \to \infty }{\lim \sup}\;  F'(x) = \infty$ (so, in particular, $F'(x)$ does not tend to $0$ as $x \to \infty$). We first define a continuous function $f:[0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ as follows: for each positive integer $n$, $f(n)=0$, $f$ is linearly increasing on the interval $\left[n,n+\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right]$, $f\left(n+\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right) = n$, $f$ is linearly decreasing on the interval $\left[n+\frac1{2^{n+1}},n+\frac1{2^n}\right]$, and $f\left(n+\frac1{2^n}\right)=0$; for any other $x$, we define $f(x)=0$. Then we have
$$
\int_0^\infty  {f(x)\,\mathrm dx}  = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty  {\int_n^{n + 2^{ - n} } {f(x)\,\mathrm dx} }  = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{n2^{-n}}{2}}  = \frac12\sum_{n = 1}^\infty  \frac{n}{2^n}  = 1.
$$
Now we define the function $F$ by $F(x) = \int_0^x {f(t)\,\mathrm dt}$. Then,
$$
\lim _{x \to \infty } F(x) = \lim _{x \to \infty } \int_0^x {f(t)\,\mathrm dt}  = \int_0^\infty  {f(t)\,\mathrm dt}  = 1.
$$
On the other hand, by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $F'(x) = f(x)$. Since, for any positive integer $n$, $f\left(n+\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right) = n$, we have 
$$
\underset{x \to \infty }{\lim \sup}\; F'(x) = \underset{x \to \infty }{\lim \sup}\; f(x) = \infty .
$$

Answer (score 9):

It's true iff $\rm\ lim\ F\,'$ exists. Andre gave a counterexample if $\rm\ lim\ F\,'$ does not exist. Conversely:

**Theorem** $\ $ If $\rm\,\ F + F\,'\!\to L\ $ as $\rm\ x\to\infty\ $ then $\rm\ F\to L,\  F\,'\!\to 0,\,\ $ by this [L'Hôpital slick trick:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42277/limit-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-as-x-goes-to-infinity/42848#42848)

$$\rm \lim_{x\to\infty}\ F(x)\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\, F(x)}{e^x}\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\, (F(x)+F\:'(x))}{e^x}\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\ (F(x)+F\:'(x)) $$

The above employs a slightly generalized form of L'Hospital's rule [mentioned here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51596/if-f-tends-to-a-positive-limit-as-x-approaches-infinity-then-f-approaches-i/51629#51629)

This folklore L'Hospital trick is somewhat notorious due to the fact that the problem appeared in Hardy's classic calculus texbook *A Course of Pure Mathematics*, but with a less elegant solution. For example, see Landau; Jones: $\:$ [A Hardy Old Problem,](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2689813) $\:$ Math. Magazine 56 (1983) 230-232. Below is a table of the various possibilities, with examples, where FTE = Fails To Exist.
[image: L'Hospitable table]
[image: L'Hospitable table explanation]

Answer (score 6):

Let
$$F(x)=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}$$
Then $\lim_{x\to\infty} F'(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: is this function continuous at $0$.

Comment: @Chandru: Continuity at $0$ isn't relevant to the question, but if you set $F(0)=0$, the function is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Jonas Meyer: Thanks for responding to the question. When first writing the answer, I had $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ at the bottom, then decided to replace with $x$, and not to bother with specifying that $F(0)=0$.  Wouldn't matter anyway, even if there were a natural non-removable discontinuity at $0$, one could splice over it in an infinitely differentiable way.