# limit of $f$ and $f''$ exists implies limit of $f'$ is 0

Tags: calculus

> Prove that if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f''(x)$ exist, then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$.

I can prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f''(x)=0$. Otherwise $f'(x)$ goes to infinity and $f(x)$ goes to infinity, contradicting the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists. I can also prove that if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists, it must be 0. So it remains to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists. I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: A related question (which 723842934 mentions he or she has already solved) was asked recently: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78810/prove-lim-limits-x-fx-0

Comment: These questions are two parts of a single question in Spivak's text.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to a recent Putnam problem, actually. By Taylor's theorem with error term, we know that for any $x$,
$$
f(x+1) = f(x) + f'(x) + \tfrac12f''(t)
$$
for some $x\le t\le x+1$. Solve for $f'(x)$ and take limits....

Comment: Nice! But there should be a solution without Taylor's theorem, because it has not been introduced in this part of the book.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ $ This follows easily from L'Hôpital's rule since

$$\rm \lim_{x\to\infty}\ f-f'\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ (f-f')}{e^x}\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ (\:f-f'+f'-f'')}{e^x}\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\ f-f''\ exists$$

See also the similar classic [Hardy old problem.](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2F%20dubuque%20%22hardy%20old%22)

Comment: Very clever one!