# Weak version of Barbalat's lemma proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, control-theory

I didn't find this result in the literature and therefore I ask you to review my proof on it:

> Given $f:]a,\infty[ \to \mathbb{R} \in C^1(]a,\infty[)$ and assume
>   that $\lim_{t \to +\infty} f(t) = L \in \mathbb{R}$.
>
> Proof that there exists a divergent sequence $t_n \to +\infty$ such
>   that $f'(t_n) \to 0$.

**Proof:**

Since $\lim_{t \to +\infty} f(t) = L \in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $\forall \epsilon > 0. \exists M > 0. x > M \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Taking $\epsilon_n = \frac{1}{n}$ we get $M_n$ such that, applying mean value theorem: $$|f'(\xi_n)| = |f'(\xi_n)||(M_n+1)-(M_n+2)| = |f(M_n+1) - f(M_n+2)| = $$ $$= |f(M_n+1) - L + L - f(M_n+2)| \le |f(M_n+1) - L| + |L - f(M_n+2)| \le \frac{2}{n}$$

and clearly, $\{f'(\xi_n)\} \to 0$. Where $\xi_n$ is an appropriate point between $M_n+1$ and $M_n+2$.

It remains to guarantee that $\xi_n \to \infty$. To do so I think a strategy would be to redefine $M_n$  as $M_0' = M_0$ and $M_n' = min\{M_{n-1}+1,M_n\}$.

Please let me know whether this proof is right or any improvements that can be made to it.

Comment: You are technically applying [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) and $\xi_n \in (M_n+1, M_n+2)$. Something similar was done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44009/does-finiteness-of-lim-limits-x-to-inftyfx-and-lim-limits-x-to-inftyf/98159#98159)

Comment: @rtybase thanks for the reference ill take a look at it as soon as i can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simpler.

One takes the sequence $n$ which obviously diverges.

For each $n$ there exists $\xi_n$ such that $f'(\xi_n)  = f(n+1)-f(n)$  by MVT.

By continuity of $f$, $f'(\xi_n) = f(n+1) - f(n) \to L - L = 0$.

Note that since $\xi_n \in ]n,n+1[$ it is also a divergent sequence.