# Re: If a function has a finite limit at infinity, does that imply its derivative goes to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let [$f(x)=x^{-1}\sin\left(x^3\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/162085/81595). It's easy to check that that the limit of $f$ at $+\infty$ is $0$ and that $f'$ doesn't have a limit. However, applying [this trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42848/81595), we can deduce that $\lim_{+\infty}f'(x)=0$. How to resolve this contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That trick requires the assumption that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) + f'(x)$ exists.

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ f(x)\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ f(x)}{e^x}$ is obvious. $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ f(x)}{e^x}\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ (f(x)+f\,'(x))}{e^x}$ is just L'Hopital's rule. $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ (f(x)+f\,'(x))}{e^x}\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\, (f(x)+f'(x))$ is also obvious. So in which step we assumed that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) + f'(x)$ exists?

Comment: The problem with that is that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}$ is not an indeterminate $\infty/\infty$ form because $e^xf(x)$ does not tend to $\infty$ (for example, because it is zero infinitely often).

Comment: @whatever L'Hopital's rule says that when the limit you get after differentiating (in this case $\lim f(x)+f'(x)$) exists, then the original limit exists and the two are equal. When the second limit doesn't exist, we can't say anything about the first one.

Comment: @Farnight Yes I totally forgot that.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Proposition, Lemma or Theorem, you always need to check if your hypothesis is fullfilled. In this case, your trick says: if $f+f' \to L$ (where $L\in\mathbb{R}$) as $x\to \infty$, then $f\to L$,$f'\to 0$. But in your case, the limit of $f'$ does not exist so the limit of $f+f'$ does not exist either.

For more detailed understanding, you see that you can not follow the same path of argumentation as in the proof with your specific example, as $lim_{x\to\infty}\ e^xf(x)$ does not exist. This means that you can not have the equality $\rm  \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ f(x)}{e^x}\ =\ \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ (f(x)+f\,'(x))}{e^x}\ \qquad$ as in the proof because it uses L'Hospital and you do not have the indeterminate form "$\infty/\infty$" for $lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x\ f(x)}{e^x}$ (because the limit of the numerator does not exist).

I hope I could help.