# A smooth function f is absolutely integrable then the function goes to 0.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Here is a question of real analysis. I am not sure whether my conjecture is true or not? Any help will be appreciated.

Suppose $\psi : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a real valued, even and sufficiently smooth (I think we have to assume higher-order derivatives exist) function. Suppose
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\exp(-\psi(t))dt=1\; \text{and}\; \int_{\mathbb{R}}|t|\exp(-\psi(t))dt<\infty.$$
I want to prove that $\lim_{|z|\to \infty}z\exp(-\psi(z))=0$. I have no idea how to proceed. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You don't need to require any smoothness on $\psi$ besides continuity perhaps. A necessary (but insufficient) condition for the convergence of an improper integral to infinity is that the integrand goes to $0$. Turning that around, if $\int_\mathbb{R} f dx < \infty$ then $f(x)$ *must* go to $0$

Comment: @NinadMunshi It was pointed out by GEdgar that this statement is actually false (you can consider $f$ to be triangles of area $1/2^n$ as a counter example)

Comment: this is  a counter example https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2434794/396668

Comment: @Yanko good point, I'll leave up my comment for anyone else that falls into the trap

Comment: I don't believe the conjecture in the OP is true, for exactly the reason that Yanko/GEdgar point out: one can make the integrand essentially the union of ever-narrower bumps so that both integrals still converge, but the integrand has no pointwise upper bound. Piecewise-linear paths are one way to accomplish this, and any such example can be approximated arbitrarily closely by real-analytic examples.