# Horizontal asymptotes and derivate function

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)$ is a real function with (1) $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f(x)=c\in\mathbb{R}$ and if I suppose that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f'(x)$ exist, then is it true that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f'(x)=0$?
Furthermore, if I suppose $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and hypothesis (1), then $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f'(x)=0$?
<!——>

Comment: It is not clear what the question is in the "*furthermore*" part. FWIW being $C^1$ and having a horizontal asymptote at $+\infty$ is not enough to guarantee that $f'$ has a limit at $+\infty$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42277/proving-that-lim-limits-x-to-inftyfx-0-when-lim-limits-x-to-inftyf, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162078/if-a-function-has-a-finite-limit-at-infinity-does-that-imply-its-derivative-goe

Comment: “then is true that $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty} f'(x)=0$?”—I think that would make sense. Your first statement says the function converges to $c$, and the next supposes the limit for the derivative exists. Since the function converges to single value, it’s slope must level off, meaning it’s derivative converges to $0$. Sorry I haven’t said this mathematically, I’m not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

From the mean-value theorem, we have

$$f(x+1)-f(x)=f'(\xi)$$

where $\xi\in(x,x+1)$.  Can you finish now?

Comment: @user910194 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach. Let $a=\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$. Then by l'Hôpitâl (for instance), we have
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=a.$$
If $a\neq 0$, $f$ wouldn't have a horizontal asymptote.