# Give an example of a function $f$ such that has a limit in $+\infty$ but $f'$ does not have a limit in $+\infty$.

Tags: analysis

If $f$ is a derivative of the interval $[0,+\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to+ \infty}:f(x)=L$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}:f'(x)= A$ and $A$ , $L$ are real numbers, then $A=0$

Give an example of a function $f$ such that has a limit in $+\infty$ but $f'$ does not have a limit in $+\infty$.

.

I'm thinking about constant functions but it's not true!

Comment: Various examples here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/162078/42969.

Comment: ${1 \over x + 1} \sin x^2$ works.