# $\sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x}}}}}}$ as composition of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Edit 1**: do **NOT** want to differentiate, the other question is about differentiation, this question is about function composition, **NOT differentiation**.

Looking at [differentiate $\sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x}}}}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4877703/differentiate-y-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx-sqrtx) (twice deleted, again) it seemed that if it can be written a composition of functions then it could be chain (saw) ruled.

[Anne Bauval's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4877713) effectively used a sequence of functions to solve the problem. It could also be a good example of the chain rule if expressed as a composition of functions.

$f(x)=\sqrt {x}$
and
$g(x)=x^2+x$
then
$$f \circ g  \circ f(x)= \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x} }$$

but this is useless after that.

My question is there a simple function composition to express $\sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x + \sqrt {x}}}}}}$

PS: I can differentiate the expression by using chain rule implicitly but looking to use the chain rule explicitly.

Comment: It seems the OP question has exactly $6$ square roots, does not continue infinitely?

Comment: @GEdgar : exactly, the funny part is the infinite case is far more trivial.

Comment: This question needs clarification: which functions are we allowed to compose? We could for instance take that function itself (composed with the identity map if you like).

Comment: @AnneBauval : "it can be written a composition of functions then it could be chain (saw) ruled." had all clarification required.

Comment: Again: I don't think so, because it lacks some constraints on the functions allowed. Your example suggests you allow only one-variable functions, and even this is not restrictive enough to avoid infinitely many trivial solutions.

Comment: @AnneBauval : thank you, my example was the best closest i came up with, I struggled with finding a single solution I could use let alone infinitely many. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be very trivially composed of one function with itself if you take a multi variable function.

Let $g(x,y) = \sqrt{x + y}$

Then $g(x,g(x,(g(x,g(x,g(x,g(x,0)))))))$.

If all you were looking for is the composition then this trivially solves it with the square root of a linear function but again, it is a function of two inputs, even though the y is a “dummy” variable such that we only plug in g and 0 into it, never actually define y as a variable.

Comment: Thank you , interesting idea. And I did not specify anything that would rule this out , just that I wouldn't ever think of something like this. Opens more possibilities to try :)

Comment: Of course!  This is pretty much the same as defining a recursive sequence of functions, except you don’t need to define each function separately, you just need to compose it n times, in this case 6.  And if for some reason you did want to differentiate it then you would have to differentiate with respect to x and y where y is a function of x and add them together because of the chain rule on (dg/dx)(x,y(x)) separates into two parts, but I forgot how to separate it off the top of my head.

Comment: This answer was indeed trivial and should have been mentionned in the question, and discarded by a more precise specification, in the spirit of the OP's  "useless" example.