# If $f(x)$ goes to zero as $x$ tends infinity, does $f'(x)$ do it as well?

Tags: calculus

Imagine you know a function obeys the following:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0
$$
Assuming that is a smooth and continuous function, is is possible to prove that it also should obey this:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0
$$
My approach:
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)  = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left (\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} \right) \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)  =  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x + h) - \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)}{h}  \\
\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)  =  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0 - 0}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{0}{h} = 0  \\
$$
Is this reasoning correct? If not, what is wrong? Are there other ways to prove this?

Comment: I do not think it is true so it cannot be proved.  Try finding the derivative of $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x^3)}{x}$ for $x>1$ and consider what values the function and its derivative can achieve

Comment: Or even $x \mapsto {\sin x^2 \over x}$.

Comment: @copper.hat - indeed, but my version has unbounded derivatives as $x$ increases

Comment: You can found a counterexample in other MSE questions, e.g., [**MSE 162078**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162078/if-a-function-has-a-finite-limit-at-infinity-does-that-imply-its-derivative-goe?rq=1)

Comment: For completeness, the error in your proof lies in the fact that, in general, you cannot interchange the order of double limits, i.e you cannot say that $\lim_{x\to x_0}\lim_{y\to y_0} g(x, y) = \lim_{y\to y_0}\lim_{x\to x_0} g(x,y)$.

Comment: @MyMathYourMath Don’t you mean to interchange function and derivative? But, even so, why is this relevant?