# Does the derivative of a bounded smooth monotone function have a limit at infinity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Let $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ a *monotonic* function such that $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = m \in \mathbb{R}$$

Does this imply $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$?

If so, can the hypothesis be relaxed?

If not, which additional condition we must require on $f(x)$ so that it works?

EDIT:

Let's require also that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ exists.

How can one prove the claim?

Comment: No. Let $f$ increase to $1$, but approximately constant most of the time except for "abrupt" (but smooth) jumps.

Comment: What you need to require on $f$ is that the limit of $f'$ exists.

Comment: @GitGud great :) Can you post a proof of the fact?

Comment: @DavidMitra I guess you're function is a counter example of the case in which we do not require the existance of $\lim f'$, right?

Comment: Yes. But that wasn't assumed in your question.

Comment: @Ant [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/42848) is a proof that will make you want to cry from how beautiful it is.

Comment: Assuming the limit exists, apply the Mean Value Theorem to $f$ on the intervals $[n,n+1]$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limit of the derivative of a function as x goes to infinity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42277/limit-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-as-x-goes-to-infinity)

Comment: I disagree that it is a duplicate. The hypothesis the OP assumes aren't the same and require different counterexamples than the usual ones.

Comment: @DavidMitra if I apply the mean value theorem we have $f(n+1) - f(n) = f'(c)$ , $c \in [n, n+1]$. Taking the limit (if $\lim f'$ exists) we have $\lim f' = 0$. So the hypothesis of monotonicity can be relaxed.. Do we still need to require that $f'(x)$ is continuos ?

Comment: @GitGud the proof was absolutely great. Thank you!

Comment: No, continuity of $f'$ isn't needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To construct a counterexample, it is easier to begin with the derivative of $f$. Define 
$$
g(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-2^n|x-n|)^+
$$
where $a^+=\max(a,0)$. The graph of $g$ consists of triangular spikes at every positive integer; the $n$th spike has height $1$ and base $2^{1-n}$, hence its area is $2^{-n}$. Define 
$$
f(x) = \int_0^x g(t)\,dt
$$
Since $g$ is continuous and nonnegative, $f$ is $C^1$ and monotone. Also, for every $x$
$$f(x)\le \sum_n 2^{-n}=1$$
which implies that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists (in fact, it is equal to $1$).

On the other hand, $f'=g$, which does not have a limit at infinity.

The proof of $\lim f'=0$ under the additional assumption that $\lim f'$ exists was [already given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42277/limit-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-as-x-goes-to-infinity).

Comment: thank you! Very nice, I figured what was wrong but having an actual example is great :)