# Derivative of Monotone Function with Limit at Infinity must be Bounded at Infinity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

It is clear from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713527/does-the-derivative-of-a-bounded-smooth-monotone-function-have-a-limit-at-infini) that the derivative of a $C^1$ monotone function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ whose limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$ exists need not have the existence of a limit.  I conjecture though that $f'$ must be bounded, though, but I cannot prove it, so I would be very grateful for some help, or a counterexample.

---

My (not particularly useful) attempt so far (this may be disregarded of course):

Without loss of generality, suppose $f$ is increasing so that $f' \ge 0$. Suppose $f'$ is not bounded.  Then there exists a sequence of numbers $x_n$ such that
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = \infty \\ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f'(x_n) = \infty$$
(the first limit is due to the fact that $f'$ is continuous and thus bounded on compact sets).  Without loss of generality, pass to a subsequence, also denoted $x_n$, such that $x_{n+1} - x_n \ge 1$.  Since $f(x)$ has a limit, say $L$, as $x \rightarrow \infty$,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = L$$
By the mean value theorem, there exists $y_n \in (x_n, x_{n+1})$ such that
$$0 \leq f(x_{n+1}) - f(x_n) = f(y_n) (x_{n+1} - x_n) \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$$
so that $f'(y_n) \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$ and I thought about trying to relate $f'(y_n)$ and $f'(x_n)$ but this idea is trash, as is my math ability lol.

Comment: The answer at the question you linked to can easily be modified to get $f'$ (also known as $g$ there) unbounded. Just make the spikes taller and narrower --- sufficiently narrow to keep the total area under them finite.

Comment: Makes sense. Just take $$g(x) \equiv \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n (1 - 2^n |x - n|)_+$$ instead of the version given there. I am sorry that I failed to see this.