# If Limit of function and derivative exist, then limit of derivative is 0

Tags: analysis, derivatives, continuity

Any hints for this question , 
My attempt;
Say $f(x):0$$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{R}$
The by MVT, there exists a $c$$\in$$(0,\infty)$ , such that;
$f'(c)=$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$
but im not sure about this step..
$\lim_{c \to +\infty}$$f'(c)$=$\lim_{x \to +\infty}$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$
I am quite sure there is a mistake, any hints would be appreciated.

> If $\lim_{x \to +\infty}$$f(x)$ exists and is finite and $\lim_{x \to +\infty}$$f'(x)=b$ then $b=0$.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/42848) answer.

Comment: ok I agree, this might be a duplicate, what are the rules? should I delete this question?

Comment: No, keep it. People will eventually close it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

There is this $e^x$ trick. Consider $$f(x)=\frac{e^x f(x)}{e^x}$$ as $x\to\infty$. Use L'Hopital.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^xf'(t)\ dt$$
So $\displaystyle\int_a^\infty f'(x)\ dx$ converges, because $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists. Buf if $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists, then it must be $0$, else the integral wouldn't converge.

Comment: the first line is only true when the derivative is a continuous function.

Comment: @mookid That's not true. $f$ only has to be differentiable. (this is of course the Newton integral)

Comment: I let you check [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part): "The Second part is somewhat stronger than the Corollary because it does not assume that f is continuous."

Comment: Another interesting point is the [absolute continuity definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity).

Comment: One nice counterexample is the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function), for which $f(1) - f(0) = 1$ but $f'(x) = 0 $ almost everywhere.

Comment: @mookid that's not differentiable everywhere. I'm using the Newton integral $\displaystyle(N)\!\!\int_a^b\!f$ which is just by definition $F(b)-F(a)$.

Comment: @mookid But still has basic properties like if $f\ge g$, then $\displaystyle(N)\!\!\int_a^b\!f\ge (N)\!\!\int_a^b\!g$ if they are both Newton integrable. Therefore my solution is valid.

Comment: @mookid No comment?

Comment: I don know anything about eh Newton integral.

Comment: @mookid It's extremely simple. If $f=F'$, then $(N)\!\!\int_a^b\!f\overset{\text{def}}{=}F(b)-F(a)$. This is independent of $F$ and it's easy to see that $f\ge0\Longrightarrow(N)\!\!\int_a^b\!f\ge0$. You immediately get that $f>c>0$ where $c\in\mathbb R$ implies $(N)\!\!\int_a^b\!f\ge(b-a)c$ and the conclusion is that if the integral in my answer converges, then $f'\to0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\limsup_{h\to 0} \left|
\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)} h - b
\right| 
 = \limsup_{h\to 0} |f'(x+\theta_{x,h} h) - b|
\le \limsup_{h\to 0} \sup_{0<\theta<1}|f'(x+\theta h) - b| =0
$$