# If $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=a$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=0$ - whats wrong with the proof?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Here's how i would prove this. Since we have that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=a$ this implies that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x + 1) - f(x)=0$ By mean value theorem we have that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x-1)}{x-(x-1)}=\lim_{c \to \infty}f'(c)=0$. QED However, quick search shows that $f(x)=\sin(x^a)/x$ is a counter example. What gives?

Comment: You only have a *sequence* of $c$ values for which $f'(c)$ approaches $0$. You certainly don't have your limit statement.

Comment: The counter-example does not have $f(x)\to a$. I think you mean $f(x) = a + \frac{\sin(x^{k})}{x}$ for some $k\geq 2$.

Comment: @Winther I think the original function denotes some arbitrary constant, as such the first condition is satisfied since $f \to 0$.

Comment: The change of variables is not justified in your proof. Indeed, $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x-1)}{x-(x-1)} \not = \lim_{c \to \infty}f'(c)$. Moreover, the proof will be valid only for a single variable; in your counterexample, $a$ is to be considered a separate variable even though it denotes a constant.

Comment: There is a simpler proof; consider what you may claim about $f$ given $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. You will have to assume the function is differentiable, therefore continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a\neq b$.

Then mean value theorem states that; if f is continuous on [a,b] and differentiable on (a,b), then **there is** an $c\in (a,b)$ such that,
$$f(b)-f(a)=f'(c).(b-a)$$
You are using mean value theorem the wrong way.

There is an elegant answer to this with l'Hopital trick. Look at this post: [Limit of the derivative of a function as x goes to infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42277/limit-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-as-x-goes-to-infinity)

Edit: Proof in above link assumes $\lim _{x\to \infty }f'$ must exist.

Comment: But note that in the linked problem there is an extra assumption, namely that $\lim f'(x)$ exists.

Comment: @David Yes, but in the solution, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }f'(x)$ not need to be exist.

Comment: I only looked at the first three answers but they all say near the start, "assume $\lim f'(x)=L$" or something similar.  Besides, if you don't assume the limit exists then the counterexample suggested in Winther's comment on this question is correct, isn't it?

Comment: @David Look at the answer with l'Hopital trick (Bill Dubuque's answer) and comments to that answer.

Comment: OK, very nice, but he is still assuming that $f+f'$ has a limit: that means it does not apply to the present problem, in which it is given only that $f$ has a limit.  And Winther's counterexample is still good I think.

Comment: @David Yes, Winther's counterexample shows that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ need not exist if the limit of $f(x)$ exists. You think right.

Comment: @David Now you mention it, i took a closer look. I think they are talking about equality $\lim(f+f')=\lim f$ when they are mentioning the non-existence of $f'$. This table (http://i.stack.imgur.com/qS98q.jpg) -which has a link from comments- summarises the situation very clearly. If $f'$ fails to exist then $\lim(f+f')$ fails to exist. If $f'$ exist then it must be 0. I think you are right. $f'$ must exist.