# Differentiation under the integral sign — where is my mistake?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, definite-integrals, fresnel-integrals

I'm trying to find

$$\int_0^\infty \sin \left( x^2 \right)\,dx$$

by the method of differentiation under the integral sign. The idea is to use differentiation with respect to $t$ on $A(t)$ — defined below — and then let $t$ approach infinity and take the square root to find the Fresnel integral.

Let

$$A(t) = \left( \int_0^t \sin(x^2)\,dx \right)^2$$

$$A'(t) = 2\sin(t^2) \int_0^t \sin(x^2)\,dx$$

Let $x=yt$

$A'(t) = 2\sin(t^2) \int_0^1 \sin(t^2y^2)t\,dy $

$A'(t) = \int_0^1 2t\sin(t^2)\sin(t^2y^2)\,dy $

$A'(t) = \int_0^1 t(\cos(t^2-t^2y^2)-\cos(t^2+t^2y^2))\,dy $

$A'(t) = \int_0^1 t(\cos(t^2(1-y^2))-\cos(t^2(1+y^2)))\,dy $

$A'(t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\frac{\sin(t^2(1-y^2))}{1-y^2}-\frac{\sin(t^2(1+y^2))}{y^2+1})\,dy $

$A'(t) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(t^2(1-y^2))}{1-y^2}-\frac{\sin(t^2(1+y^2))}{y^2+1} \, dy $

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$\int A'(t)\,dt + C = A(t)$

If we take the limit as $\lim_{t\to 0}$:

**EDIT: $\lim_{t\to 0} \int{A'(t)dt} + C = \lim_{t\to 0}A(t)$**

$\lim_{t\to 0} \int{A'(t)dt} = 0$ and $\lim_{t\to 0}A(t) = 0$

So $0 + C = 0$ and $C=0$

Thus, $\int A'(t)\,dt = A(t)$,

But, if we take the limit as $\lim_{t\to \infty}$:

**EDIT: $\lim_{t\to \infty} \int{A'(t)dt} = \lim_{t\to \infty}A(t)$**

I haven't been able to confirm it, but I am pretty sure from numerical calculations that $\lim_{t\to \infty} \int{A'(t)dt} = 0$.

But we know that $\lim_{t\to \infty}A(t)$ should be $\pi/8$.

And $0\neq \pi/8$.

I may have made a simple algebra or calculus mistake, but I haven't caught it.

You help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't read through the middle of your argument, but $\lim A'(t)=0$ does not imply $\lim A(t)=0$. Why would it, when you can add a constant to $A(t)$ and change the second limit but not the first? Indeed if the limit $\lim A(t)$ exists at all, then we should expect $\lim A'(t)=0$ (see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42277/limit-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-as-x-goes-to-infinity)).

Comment: The idea is to figure out the constant by taking the limit as t approaches 0. The constant should be the same no matter where you are taking the limit, so I believe this argument should hold. As t approaches 0, both $A](t)$ and $A(t)$ approach zero, so I concluded that C = 0. 

I believe that C should equal $\pi/2$, but I don't think that step is the mistake (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Consider $A(t)=\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau$ for any other nice $f$ for which $\int_0^\infty f(\tau)d\tau$ converges. According to you, since $A(0)=0$ and $A'(0)=0$, we must have $\lim A(t)=0$, i.e. **every** integral $\int_0^\infty f(\tau)d\tau$ is zero! There has to be logic that connects your facts to your conclusions, otherwise you have a non sequitur.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your logic, as $A'(0) \neq 0 $ for all A(t) for which $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(t)dt$. If we consider the Gaussian function, $f(x) = e^{-x^2/2}$, we can do the same procedure and achieve the right result (full analysis on pages 4-5 of [this pdf](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf)).

Comment: Sorry, I needed to add the condition $f(0)=0$, you're right. Anyway, in your new revision, you've written the correct equation $\int_0^t A'(\tau)d\tau+C=A(t)$, but then your next equation is $\lim A'(t)+C=\lim A(t)$. Where did the $\int$ sign go?

Comment: You can't take a limit of an *indefinite* integral, and yet you have $\lim\int$ written a few times in your argument.

Comment: Why do you have $y^2-1$ in one of the denominators? Shouldn't it be $1-y^2$?

Comment: @whacka Yes, it should be $1-y^2$. Unfortunately, the negation doesn't resolve the contradiction because the term still approaches 0 as t approaches 0 or $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

I stopped reading when I got to the first mistake. When you set $x=ty$, you forgot to put $dx=tdy$ in your integral.

Comment: Sorry I did that on paper and forgot to include it when writing the post. The next step (antidifferentiation) is correct taking into account $dx=tdy$ (I believe).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}A'(t)=0$ to conclude $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}A(t)=0$. In fact, something of the opposite is true: for *any* limit $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} A(t)=L$ of a nice function $A$, its existence implies $\lim_{t\to\infty}A'(t)=0$, no matter what the original limit $L=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}A(t)$ is. Indeed, adding a constant to the function $A(t)$ will alter the value of the limit $L=\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}A(t)$ but it will not change the fact that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty}A'(t)=0$.

It is also not true that analyzing the behavior of a function $A(t)$ and its derivative $A'(t)$ near the value $t=0$ will tell us what happens for $A(t)$ as we take $t\to\infty$. For instance, $A(t)=A'(t)=0$ is completely possible even if $A(t)$ is increasing on the interval $(0,\infty)$. This is a *local-global* distinction: what happens locally does not generally what happens globally. There are certain exceptions, for instance with an analytic function, but even with analytic functions we would have to specify *all* of the values $A(0)$, $A'(0)$, $A''(0)$, $A'''(0)$, $\cdots$ in order to force any determination of what happens to $A(t)$ as  we take $t\to\infty$.

In particular, suppose we accept the logic that $A(0)=A'(0)=0$ implies $A(t)\to0$ as $t\to\infty$, which we know is not true by considering for instance $A(t)$ increasing on $(0,\infty)$. If we define the function $A(t)=\int_0^t f(\tau)d\tau$ for any nice function $f$ for which $\int_0^\infty f(\tau)d\tau$ converges and $f(0)=0$, this logic would imply that **any and all integrals** $\int_0^\infty f(\tau)d\tau$ (with $f(0)=0$) **are zero**!

If you want an explicit example, consider $f(\tau)=\tau^2e^{-\tau}$. Then $f(0)=0$, and $A(0)=0$ but $A(t)=\int_0^t \tau^2e^{-\tau}d\tau\to \Gamma(3)=2$ as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: So sorry for my mistake. I wrote it down correctly on my paper and copied it incorrectly into the post. Please see my edits on the original post -- I unfortunately still do not know the error. I completely understand that the limit of $A'(t)$ does not equal the limit of $A(t)$, as the limit of $A'(t)$ for any convergent improper integral will always be 0. I meant to be talking about $\int{A'(t)dt}$ the whole time. It does make sense that $\int{A'(t)dt} + C = A(t)$ for some C, right.

Comment: @DeltaEffects When you say you've numerically investigated $\int A'(t)dt$, you mean $\int_0^t A(\tau)d\tau$ right? Like I said above, you cannot take a limit of an indefinite integral, you should be writing definite integrals.

Comment: When taking the limit of $\int{A'(t)dt}$, I'm taking the limit as t approaches infinity of a function of t (which has a definite integral with respect to y inside of it), so I think it makes sense. I've investigated the following: 

$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \int A'(t)dt
= \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(t^2(1-y^2))}{y^2-1}-\frac{\sin(t^2(1+y^2))}{y^2+1}dy$

Comment: **Do not write** $\lim_{t\to\infty}\int A'(t)dt$. The notation $\int A'(t)dt$ does not refer to a unique function of $t$, it refers to an entire *class* of functions of $t$.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Next time, I'll write out the full integral or use different notation. I am trying to convey the limit as t approaches infinity of the definite integral with respect to y above, as the constant obtained by antidifferentiation of $A'(t)$ appears to equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach will work. But if you know that

$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$, then you can do a contour integral

$\int _{c}e^{-z^{2}}dz$, where $c$ is the line $0$ to $r$, then counterclockwise from $r$ to $re^{i\pi /4}$, and finally back along the line from $re^{i\pi /4}$ to $0$. This is a closed contour and the integrand is analytic inside $c$, so the integral must be $0$. Calculating the integrals along the pieces of the contour, letting $r\rightarrow \infty$ will give you the result.

Comment: I haven't learned much about contour integration, so I'm trying to work out the integral with only real methods. I know this method works on $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ (can link a source if you would like), so I can't figure out why it doesn't work here. I'll be sure to revisit this method when I have more tools at my disposal!

Comment: Read carefully the other comments here. They pretty much show your method won't work I think. As far as I know, these types of integrals are done by jumping into the complex plane and doing contour integration,The integral shown at the start of my answer is kind of a special case. By doing a trick and switching to polar coordinates, you get the answer without resorting to complex integration. But for sines and cosines of the type youhave, I think contour integration is the way to go.  By the way, the integral you are showing is divergent!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to negate the exponent: $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$. There's no doubt that it can be done with contour integration -- I'm just trying to figure out why this way isn't working. It worked well for the Gaussian and the answers here (while they have addressed a number mistakes I made in typing my method) have not shown definitively why the method (or one of the steps) fails.