# Relation between bounded derivative and limit of a function

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable real function such
>   that
>
> 1. $f(0) = 0$
> 2. $f'(x) \le -\frac{1}{2}$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> Then it is always true that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f^{2}(x)  = +\infty$?

I could not find a counterexample neither prove this statement. 
I only could prove that if a counterexample $g$ exists, then 
$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)$ is not finite or $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g'(x)$ is not finite. For otherwise, [it can be proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42277/limit-of-the-derivative-of-a-function-as-x-goes-to-infinity) that $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g'(x) = 0$, contradicting (2).

Similarly, if a counterexample $g$ exists, then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)$ is not finite or $g'$ is not uniformly continuous. For otherwise, by [Barbalat's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Barbalat.27s_lemma_and_stability_of_time-varying_systems), then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g'(x) = 0$, again contradicting (2).

Comment: Source of the problem, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is a special case of Exercise 4.10(b) of Khalil's book [Nonlinear Systems](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=t_d1QgAACAAJ). I was thinking that $V(x)$ was not going to be radially unbounded and tried to produce a counterexample using a scalar valued function $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its almost obvious. Clearly the derivative is negative so as $x$ increases $f(x)$ decreases and hence $f(x) \to -\infty$ or $f(x) \to L$ as $x \to \infty$. If $f(x) \to L$ then by MVT $f'(c) = f(x + 1) - f(x) \to 0$ and this contradicts $f'(x) \leq -1/2$. Hence it follows that $f(x) \to -\infty$ and hence $f^{2}(x) \to \infty$. The result holds even if $(-1/2)$ of the question is replaced by any negative number.

Comment: Is the use of MVT to justify that $f'(x) \to 0$ correct? It is very well possible for a continuously differentiable function to tend to a limit without the derivative tending to 0 (see bullet point 2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_stability#Barbalat.27s_lemma_and_stability_of_time-varying_systems)

Comment: @Nitin: I agree that *it is very well possible for a continuously differentiable function to tend to a limit without the derivative tending to $0$*. What I am saying is that $f(x + 1) - f(x) \to 0$ and hence for every $\epsilon > 0$ we have an $N > 0$ such that $|f(x + 1) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x > N$. This means that there will infinitely many values of $c$ such that $N < x < c < x + 1$ such that $|f'(c)| < \epsilon$ and this contradicts $f'(x) < -1/2$ as soon as $0 < \epsilon < 1/2$. I am sorry if my wording suggested that $f'(x) \to 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Before editing the second condition was $f'\le 1/2$. In that case the statement is false. As a counterexample consider the function $x\mapsto \sin(0.5x)$ or $x\mapsto 0.5\sin x$

---

Now, with the new statement. For every $x\ge 0$ we have:
$$
f(x)=\int_0^xf'(t)\,dt\le -\frac{x}{2} \le 0.
$$
It follows that
$$
f^2(x)\ge \frac{x^2}{4} \quad \forall x\ge 0,
$$
and therefore
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f^2(x)\ge \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^2}{4}=\infty.
$$