# If the limits at infinity of $f$ and $f'$ exist and are finite, then is $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such
>   that both the limits $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ and $\lim_{x
> > \rightarrow \infty} f'(x)$ exist and are finite. Is $\lim_{x
> > \rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = 0$ necessarily?

This is true. Let $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = M$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$. Suppose $M > 0$, there exists some $A_1 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x > A_1$, 
$$ f'(x) > \frac{M}{2}$$
Given $\epsilon = \frac{M}{4} > 0$, there exists $A_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that whenever $x > A_2$,
$$|f(x) - L| < \frac{M}{4}$$
For $x, y > A_2$, we have 
$$ |f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x) - L| + |f(y) - L| < \frac{M}{2}$$
Let $A = \max\,\{A_1, A_2\}$. Take $x > A$, then applying LMVT on $[x, x+1]$,
there exists some $c \in (x, x+1)$ such that
$$ |f(x+1) - f(x)| = |f'(c)| > \frac{M}{2}$$
But as $x > A_2$, $$|f(x + 1) - f(x)| < \frac{M}{2}$$
This is a contradiction, so $M > 0$ must be false.

Similarly, we can prove that $M < 0$ does not hold. Thus, $M = 0$.

Does this proof work? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/42277/148510

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f'(x) \to l$ in $+\infty$.

If $l > 0$ then $\exists \  A$ such that $\forall x > A \ f'(x) > l/2 > 0$. So $f(x) > l/2*x + C \to +\infty$. Contradiction. The same if $l<0$.

Comment: Thanks! Did that last step involve using the fundamental theorem of calculus, and the property that if $f \leq g$, $\int_a^b f \leq \int_a^b g$?

Comment: Yes the fundamental theorem is used with that property. It's pretty fast like that.