# A question on limit at infinity of differentiable function $f: \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$ is a differentiable function and $g(x)=e^x \cdot f(x)$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x)+f'(x)) = 0$, find the limit:
$$\lim\limits_{x, y \to \infty} \frac{g(x)-g(y)}{e^x-e^y}$$

I know from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42848/500398) that $f(x)$ goes to zero as $x$ goes to infinity. Can I get hints on how to find the desired limit?

Comment: Cauchy's mean value theorem night be helpful (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PhoemueX has pointed out, we can use [CMVT](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CauchysMean-ValueTheorem.html) to solve this. Verify that the assumptions to apply CMVT hold. Now see that $\exists \ z \in (x,y)$ (assuming [WLOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) $x < y$) such that

$$ \frac{g(x) - g(y)}{e^x - e^y} = \frac{g'(z)}{e^z} = \frac{e^z(f(z) + f'(z))}{e^z} = f(z) + f'(z).$$

Apply limits on both sides to get $$\lim_{x,y \to \infty} \frac{g(x) - g(y)}{e^x - e^y} = \lim_{\substack{z \ \in \ (\min(x,y),\max(x,y)) \\ x,y \ \to \ \infty}} (f(z) + f'(z)) = 0.$$