# Does there exist a real valued differentiable function such that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 2$ and $\lim_{ n\rightarrow \infty} f'(x) =1$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, contest-math

This question appeared in my exam (in my university entrance test).

Question: Does there exist a real valued differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 2$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x) =1$?

My attempt: $2=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))=2+1=3$. Hence contradiction!

Am I correct?

$\textbf{Has anyone seen this problem before in college contests, problem book etc.?}$ If you have seen this problem before please let me know.

Comment: Nice, but not new: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/42848/42969

Comment: Yours seems correct and elegant @user1234

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = 1$, then there is some $C > 0$ such that $f'(x) > \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x \geq C$. It follows that
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(C) + \int^x_C f'(s)~\mathrm{d}s \geq f(C) + \int^x_C \frac{1}{2}~\mathrm{d}s = f(C) + \frac{x-C}{2} \overset{x \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty.
$$
So such function can't exist.

Comment: As above, if a function goes to a fixed value, it's derivative must eventually approach 0. A derivative of 1 means it keeps increasing

Comment: He used l'Hospital rule.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. His seems correct at first sight, although I do not know whether l'Hopital can be used if the fraction is not shortened. Guess it can't, since his limit cannot be correct.

Comment: Unless I am terribly mistaken, the proof in the question is correct, and the question is a duplicate.

Comment: Might be true...

Comment: by changing $0$ to $C$ you have $\frac{(x-C)}{2}$ too.

Comment: ofc, thank you!