$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f'(x)\geq0$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$？
Is it correct to say that if a function $f$ of class $C^1$ $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and $f'(x)\geq0$,then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$?
I tried to prove this problem using proof by contradiction. Specifically, assuming that $f'(x)$ does not converge to $0$, It implies
$\exists \varepsilon>0,\forall M>0,\exists x(x\geq M \ \text{and} \ f'(x)\geq \varepsilon)$.$f$ is class $C^1$, then

a sequence of disjoint closed intervals $[a_1,b_1],[a_2,b_2],\cdots$ where $f'(x)\geq \dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}$ exists.
$f(x)=\displaystyle\int_a^xf'(t)dt+f(a)$

I tried using these two, attempting to demonstrate that $f$ has a positive lower bound, but I couldn't.

No. Take your favourite $C^\infty$ non-negative function $g$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)$ doesn't exist and $\int_0^\infty g(t),dt<\infty$, then set $f(x)=\int_0^x g(t),dt-\int_0^\infty g(t),dt$.

Your approach can lead to an example where $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$ does not exist. Think of intervals $[a_j, b_j] = [j,j+2^{-j}]$.

If $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)$ exists then I think we can conclude $\lim_{x\to \infty} f'(x)  = 0$

Thank you.I will try.

@AnneBauval I know better than putting that comment of mine in an answer. Moreover, I wouldn't like writing it with the required details, so I won't.

@Sam You are correct: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42277

Does this answer your question? If a function has a finite limit at infinity, does that imply its derivative goes to zero? Especially this answer, expanding the first comment above.

@SassatelliGiulio is it essential that $g$ is $C^{\infty}$?

@SineoftheTime Obviously not.

@SassatelliGiulio But since $f'(x) \geqslant 0$ we have $f(x)$ is non-decreasing so it must be $f(x) \leqslant 0$ and the example given by you does not satisfy this condition

@RupertRybka Of course they do: all $f$ such as the one I have described are strictly negative.

@SassatelliGiulio Oh yes you are right
