# $L=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))$ exists . Which of the following statements is\are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f$ be a continously differentiable function on $\mathbb R$.  Suppose that

$$L=\lim_{x\to\infty}(f(x)+f'(x))$$ exists.  If $0<L<\infty$, then which of the following statements is\are correct?

> > 1. If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ exists, then it is $0$.
> > 2. If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists, then it is $L$.
> > 3. If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.
> > 4. If $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$.

**My Guess**

I could not conclude the answer and prove that properly. But, I guess that it must be 1 and 2. help me.

Comment: Note that under the assumption, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists if and only if $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)$ exists. That makes several of the options equivalent.

Comment: Show that $f'\to L > 0$ implies that $f$ is unbounded because $f(x) = f(0) + \int_0^x f'(t)dt$ can be arbitrarily large.

Comment: You said that you could not "prove that properly".  How did you come to your conclusion, then?  Is there anyway we can take your intuitive notion of the problem and formalize it?

Comment: In 3 do you mean $\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)$?

Comment: @ Noah : Limit of the derivative of $f$ as $x \to \infty$

Comment: Look at the second limit. I think you mean $\lim_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=0$ not $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about 1 and 2.

Note also that 2 implies 4, since
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = L - \lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)
$$
(assuming the latter limit exists).

---

Note that for arbitrary functions $g,h$: if $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)$ both exist, then
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} [g(x) \pm h(x)] = 
\lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) \pm \lim_{x \to \infty} h(x)
$$

Comment: is it true??@omnomnomnom

Comment: Is what true?  I told you that 1 and 2 are true, and yes: it is true that 2 implies 4.

Comment: i think it will not hold always..@Omnmnomnom

Comment: **what is it** that you do not think will hold always?  Do you think that it will not always hold that 2 implies 4?

Comment: yes...kindly clarify me...i am having a doubt in spliting the limit.

Comment: that you have $lim (f'(x)+f(x))=\lim f'(x)+\lim f(x)$..

Comment: Well, note that
$$
\lim f' = \lim[f + f'] - \lim f
$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19671/discussion-between-gloom-and-omnomnomnom).

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** Check this: $$\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{e^xf(x)}{e^x} \color{red}{=} \lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{e^x(f(x)+f'(x))}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)+f'(x) = L,$$ by $\color{red}{\text{L'Hospital's rule}}$.

Comment: I learned that here!

Comment: thanks your prompt reply and very tricky answer

Comment: @IvoTerek Seems there is a tacit assumption that $e^xf(x) \to \infty$ as $x\to \infty$.  Perhaps it is obvious, but the possibility (or not) that $e^xf(x)$ does not approach $\infty$ warrants a bit of discussion.  Otherwise +1

Comment: @Dr.MV, though it's not usually stated as such, L'Hopital's rule for $f(x)/g(x)$ only requires that $g(x) \to \pm \infty$, not necessarily $f(x)$ as well.

Comment: I [found the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42276/limit-of-a-function-integration-problem/51816#51816) where I saw the trick for the first time (good thing we can mark questions as favorites). I think the table there resumes the situation..

Comment: @IvoTerek I didn't hear back from you regarding the tacit assumption that $e^xf(x) \to \pm \infty$ as $x\to \infty$.   If this is not the case, then the use of [L'Hospital's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) is not valid even though the result is unchanged.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Interesting statement.  Do you have a reference for that?  All versions of "The Rule" that I have seen require the indeterminant form along with existence of the limit of the ratio of derivatives.

Comment: @Dr.MV It's mentioned very briefly in the wikipedia article for the rule (see the end of the second-to-last paragraph in the General Form section), and I have seen a proof for that case somewhere, but unfortunately I don't know an official reference for it.  It seems that the proof on Wikipedia shows it, though.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks!  Very interesting indeed.  The limit on $f$ need not even exist.  I found this [reference](http://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=686) in the Wiki article.  Amazing that this result does not seem to be as well known and its application is not as wide-spread.

Comment: Hi guys. Sorry for disappearing, I couldn't stop much at the computer today. Thanks Antonio Vargas for providing the reference!

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

If $\lim f'(x) = M$, then $\lim f(x) = L-M$

Use the MVT: $f(x+1) - f(x) = f'(\xi)$ with $x < \xi < x+1$.

Comment: kindly give details.. I couldnt understand.@rrl

Comment: @gloom:  Notice $\lim [ f(x+1) - f(x)] = L-M - (L-M) = 0$  So $\lim f'(\xi) = 0$ where $\xi$ is carried along with $x$.

Comment: oh.. thank you.. so much..@rrl

Comment: so.. 4 also follows right??@rrl

Answer (score 3):

1. If $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists, then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L-\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ also exists. Then
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)
   &=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}(f(x+1)-f(x))\\
   &=\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x+1)-\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)\\
   &=0\tag{1}
   \end{align}
   $$
2. If $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, then $(1)$ implies that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ and therefore,
   $$
   \begin{align}
   \lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)
   &=L-\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)\\
   &=L\tag{2}
   \end{align}
   $$
3. If $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists, then $(1)$ and $(2)$ say that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$.
4. If $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists, then $(1)$ implies that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$.