# If $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ is a finite real number and $f''(x)$ is bounded, then $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I was trying to prove this and I did a very similar argument as the one in this answer: [What does $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$ say about $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35869/what-does-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fx-1-say-about-lim-limits-x-to-i)

Basically,  $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x) \neq 0$ would imply that $f$ is not bounded, so its limit is not finite.

However, the theorem I was trying to prove makes the hypothesis that **$f''(x)$ is bounded**. Is this hypothesis necessary? 
It's sort of strange, because using just the argument I used would mean that (considering $f$ in n times differentiable) has all its derivatives equal to $0$.

Comment: See the following questions http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396707/if-fx-to-0-as-x-to-infty-and-f-is-bounded-show-that-fx-to0-as-x and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/730411/behavior-of-fx-as-x-to-infty-given-the-behavior-of-fx-and-fx

Comment: especially see the proof by J E Littlewood http://math.stackexchange.com/a/391864/

Answer (score 2):

> Basically, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)\not=0$ would imply that f is not bounded, so its limit is not finite.

Counterexample:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x} = 0$$
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{2x^2\cos(x^2) - 2x\sin(x^2)}{x^2} \text{ DNE}$$

Note that your original question did not presume that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exist.

Comment: @robjohn We are considering $f(x)$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is finite. $f(x)=\sin(x)$ fails to satisfy this.

Comment: I was finding a contradiction to the original question, by showing an example where $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is a finite real number, but $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)\not=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.