# What will be the value of 'b'?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \Bbb{R}$ be differentiable and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f(x)=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=b$.
Find the value of $b$.

I assume $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{x+1}$. I found above is true. But how to prove formally? I wanna prove it by **MVT**.
How to proceed? As given $f$ is differentiable then we can use formula of derivative.
But how?
Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: Perhaps knowing that the answer is $0$ will point you in the right line of thinking.

Comment: If $b>0$ then  use MVT on $[n, n+1]$ and conclude that $f(n) \to \infty$ as $ n \to \infty$. Similarly rule out $b <0$.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy: How $f(n)\to \infty$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: @Joseph $f(n+1)>(b/2)+f(n)$ for $n$ large enough.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$ say about $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f'(x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35869/what-does-lim-limits-x-to-infty-fx-1-say-about-lim-limits-x-to-i)

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a  proof with the help of **MVT**

Comment: Assuming $f(x)=\frac{x}{x+1}$ leads nowhere. You can't prove anything that way. Also, note that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=1$ is not in itself sufficient to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists. (You should try to find a counterexample!) But the question tells you that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ does indeed exist, so you can try assuming that $b\ne 0$ and deriving a contradiction using MVT.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative method: if $f'(x) → b >0$, then by definition, there is some $X>0$ such that

$$x>X \implies |f'(x) - b| > b \implies f'(x) > b/2.$$

Then, for $x > X$,

$$f(x) = f(X) + \int_X^x f'(y)\; dy \geq f(X) + \int_X^x b/2\; dy = f(X) + \frac b2(x-X).$$

I.e., $f(x) \geq \frac b2(x-X).$

(Similarly if $b<0$.)

Answer (score 2):

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)=1$
or $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}=1$ . It is $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$ form.

As $f(x)$ is differentible in ($0$, $\infty$), using *L’Hospital’s rule*, $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{e^xf(x)}{e^x}= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{e^xf(x)+ e^xf'(x)}{e^x}= \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)+ f'(x)$ which is given to be equal to $1$.

Therefore $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f'(x)=0$.

Comment: I am looking for a formal method. but this is easy(+1).

Comment: Intuitively one can imagine that f(x) is approching a fixed value as x tends to infinity so f'(x) must be equal to 0 as x tends to infinity. e^x gives shape to that intuition.

Comment: This doesn't work. According to your argument, for any differentiable $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$, we must have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$. But this is [manifestly false](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/35871/1508). See for instance [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) for the conditions that must be satisfied before L'Hôpital's rule can be invoked.

Comment: It should be mentioned that if limx→∞f′(x) exists, then the limit must be 0. If limx→∞f′(x) exists then this method is correct.

Comment: Yes. But that is something that you have to prove, using an argument similar to GoodBoy's. Your method is the wrong way to go about this.